# Combine find_all beautiful soup tags into one string

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm performing a scrape using beautifulsoup and html parser and have selected the part of the html I want to work with and saved this as 'containers'.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import ssl

my_url = 'https://www._________.co.uk/'
context = ssl._create_unverified_context()
uClient = uReq(my_url, context=context)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"row"})
```

I've got a challenge when it comes to a couple of  tags which are all next to one another in a span.

I can bring up the result by using

```
company_string = container.span.find_all("b")
```

Which returns the following:

```
[<b>Company</b>, <b>Name</b>, <b>Limited</b>]
```

How can I ditch the  tags and combine these into a string so that it outputs as 'Company Name Limited'?

Original html is here:

```
<span class="company">
<a href="/cmp/Company-Name-Limited" onmousedown="this.href = 
appendParamsOnce(this.href, 'xxxx')" rel="noopener" target="_blank">
<b>Company</b> <b>Name</b> <b>Limited</b>
</a>
</span>
```

Comment: you can use element.get_text() method to get the value of element instead of complete element.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `.text`

```
>>> output = ' '.join([item.text for item in company_string])
'Company Name Limited'
```

Comment: Perfect! Just the job. Thanks Akash

Answer (score 1):

try the following:-

```
outputString = ' '.join([item.get_text() for item in company_string])
```

It will return a string containing values of all elements concatenated with space.